# Firebase Cloud Messaging not working on production mode in angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Error:

```
Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. ServiceWorker script at https://xxxxxx/firebase-messaging-sw.js for scope https://xxxxxxxx/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope encountered an error during installation. (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).
```

Firebase is perfectly working on localhost but when I upload the build on server the above error starts showing.

Directory Structure:

```
src
   app
   assets
   environments
   favicon.io
   firebase-messaging-sw.js
   index.html
   main.ts
   manifest.json
   polyfills.ts
   styles.scss
   test.ts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching and trying, I found out that I missed registering firebase-messaging-sw.js in assets (page- angular.json). This solved my issue.